# Understanding the code behind a gridtraveller

Tags: python, grid, definition, function-definition

I found a basic code in python to find the numbers of paths you can take in a (m,n) grid if you can only go either down or right.

```
 def gridtraveller(m,n):
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 0
    elif m == 1 or n == 1:
        return 1
    return gridtraveller(m-1,n) + gridtraveller(m,n-1)
```

But I dont understand why is this working for two thing:
What does def something (m,n) do ?
And why does here we return the definition ? ( I do understand why we return
m-1 and n-1 , but I don't understant the concepte of a def returning a def)

Thanks to you and sorry english is not my first language.

Comment: `def` is a python keyword for defining a function object: `def func():` defines what calling `func` does, `func` is the function object and `func()` is calling that function. the function you are describing is using recursion (if it goes that far), it simply calls this function again inside the function and then it may call it again until it either reaches recursion max depth or returns some actual value when it just goes back the function ladder and sums it all up

Comment: I suggest tho that you take a look at some basic tutorials (such as [these by Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYXdXT2l-Gg&list=PL-osiE80TeTskrapNbzXhwoFUiLCjGgY7)) specifically this one (on topic): [Python Tutorial for Beginners 8: Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Os0o3wzS_I&list=PL-osiE80TeTskrapNbzXhwoFUiLCjGgY7&index=8), also this is on topic about [recursion](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_recursion.asp) and search for other sources if you need to understand this better

Comment: Thanks to you I will go take a look right now

Answer (score 0):

In Python the `def` keyword is simply used to define a function, in this case it's the function `gridtraveller(m,n)`. What you're seeing with that last return statement is actually a function returning the value of another function. In this case it's returning the value of another call to `gridtraveller`, but with different parameter values; this is called recursion. An important part of recursion is having appropriate base cases, or  return values that won't end in another recursive call(i.e. the `return 0` or `return 1` you see).

It can be easier to understand by simply stepping through a few iterations of the recursive calls. If your first function call starts with `m = 2` and `n = 1`, the first call will end with `return gridtraveller(1,1) + gridtraveller(2,0)`. The first call in that statement will then return `1` since either `m` or `n` are `1` and the second returns `0` since `n = 0` here giving a total result of `1`. If larger values of `m` and `n` are used it will obviously result in a higher number since more calls to `gridtraver(m,n)` will happen.